# Dynamic creation of list and adding HTML Tags in the each newly created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridster

I am using gridster for one of my project and my main aim is to create the widgets dynamically.The number of widgets I need to create will come from backend(Django).But for now I want to write a simple javascript code to create the widgets dynamically and I am hardcoding the value of the number of dynamic widgets
After reading a bit I found the following code

```
<ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
var ul = document.createElement("ul");
document.body.appendChild(ul);

for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
   var li = document.createElement("li");  
   li.className = "file";

   var a = document.createElement("a");
   a.innerHTML = 1;

  li.appendChild(a);
  ul.appendChild(li);
}

</script>
```

But my one li element is like following

```
 <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"><button class="delete-button" style="float: right;">-</button><h3>1</h3></li>
```

So in above code I am replacing

```
a.innerHTML = 1;
```

with

```
a.innerHTML =<button class="delete-button" style="float: right;">-</button>
<h3>3</h3>
```

But this is not working at all.I even know that this is not exactly what I want But this is just a step before the actual desired output

This is just 2nd day I have started with jquery/javascript and gridster
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: _“But this is not working at all”_ - no wonder, because this is not even valid/syntactically correct JavaScript.  You need to go learn some JavaScript basics first of all - preferably before you start using advanced plugins.

Comment: You should use `.append()` when you want to add a child to another element. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append
So for example:
`a.innerHTML =<button class="delete-button" style="float: right;">-</button>
<h3>3</h3>`
Should be something like:
`var button = document.createElement("button");`
`a.append(button)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a.innerHTML =<button class="delete-button" style="float: right;">-</button>
<h3>3</h3>
```

You are trying to append elements to another element. This means that `a` will become the parent element, and `button` and `h3` will become child elements.

To do this we first have to create the `button` like so:

```
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.classList.add('delete-button');
button.style.cssFloat = 'right';
```

Then we create the `h3`:

```
var h3 = document.createElement('h3');
h3.innerHTML = '3';
```

Then we append the elements to the `a`:

```
a.append(button);
a.append(h3);
```

This should do what you want :)

Comment: Thanks This is a lot helpful for a beginner

Comment: To the li element can i do like li.data-row="1" then li.data-col="1" ?

Comment: @Rookie_123 Use `setAttribute` for that, example on how to use it can be found here:
https://plainjs.com/javascript/attributes/setting-getting-and-removing-data-attributes-8/

Comment: This still creates invalid HTML ... you simply can not put other interactive elements, such as a button, into a link to begin with. (No idea why OP felt compelled to insert the link here in the first place though.)